# Lag using Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 and a strange workaround

Tags: 18.04, xfce, performance, optimization, ubuntu-budgie

I was experiencing a lot of lag using my Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 these days. The lag appeared in all basic operations (ALT + TAB, worksapace changes, programs opening, etc), but mostly when I type. To get a feel of what I've experiencing, if I just hammer keys fast and randomly in any text editor or browser, the text - that should appear instantly as I type - freezes in my screen and lag a lot until the system succed in show it completely. As this behavior was observed in Firefox, Chrome, Gedit and Visual Studio Code, I've understood that is a OS problem.

Since it started happening, I've always checked `htop` and `proc/cpuinfo` to see if some process was overloading my system... and found nothing. My CPU is almost 85% idle, so it don't seen to be a resources problem (i5 processor, Samsung SSD, 8 GB DDR4 RAM).

Trying to solve it I've installed XFCE to see if this behavior would appear in anoter DE. And yes, it showned again. In Chrome and in Visual Studio Code, the same problem ... a little less intense, I guess, but the problem is there. Get back to my Budgie Desktop with a session logout...

... and them, **all system lag has gone.** Yes, I'm not exagerating... **all system lag has simply dissapeared.** No ALT+TAB lag, no workspace change lag... I'm typing this message with not a single inch of lag. I opened Visual Studio Code (where the lag is just to big) and there is no lag... even if I type for 1 minute straight, all keys are shown instantly, fast as a god!

What could have happened here? How can I understand this problem and solve it permanently?

P.S.: Another strange behavior: the system started to try to print some documents in a printer I'd installed. I'm at home now, the printer is at my workplace's network... of course it cannot print anything from here. I've unnistaled the printer to see - I don't have much hope on that - the printer was the culprit.

Comment: So your issue was resolved by clearing the printer queue basically ? You may want to post an answer to document this

Comment: As a side note: if you have a 4 core/8 thread processor (e.g. 8th gen mobile i5), each thread contributes 12.5% to the overall CPU usage. If a single process utilizes 15% CPU, this means it is maxing out one thread on turbo boost.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I'm not clear that "clearing the printer" was the solution. All I can say right now is that after I've install XFCE4, Budgie became lighter, lagless.

Comment: I get what is the problem... using `dmesg` I saw a bunch of errors in the ePCI port. This post helped me to fix it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327730/what-causes-this-pcieport-00000003-0-pcie-bus-error-aer-bad-tlp